# How to access assets in other folders in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to access this image in my component.
I know how to add images in root directory files with `'./assets/image.png'`
But not able to add in this `iteamscomponents.js`

[image]

[image]

I added this code in `iteamscomponents.js`

but it gives an error `undefined Unable to resolve module ./assets/icons8_search_200px_3.png from components\ItemsComponent.js:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your path would be

`../assets/icons8_search_200px_3.png`

The two dots are important, it tells the cursor to navigate one folder up. One dot means stay in the same folder.